# Resample dataframe

Tags: python, date, time, series

When I do df1.resample('D') I expect having dates like this but I have the day with time. I also want to remove  after the hour
here is my code :

```
df1.resample('D').sum()
```

result

```
ts                          total 
2021-02-05 00:00:00+00:00   0
2021-02-06 00:00:00+00:00   507086
2021-02-07 00:00:00+00:00   73288
```

i want to remove this 00:00:00 and also +00:00
also i have the same issue with df.resample('H') i have with hours +00:00
thanks for helping me

Comment: This is just the standard formatting of a `datetime` object. If you want to format it differently, you can use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), eg. `df['ts'] = df['ts'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`.

Comment: you can use `df['ts'].dt.tz_localize(None)` to remove the localtime